# FreeCAD - where are the library files?

Tags: cad

I downloaded FreeCAD 0.18 from the Ubuntu Software (snap).
I don't know where are the libraries, so i can do

```
import FreeCAD
```

and run standalone Python programs with FreeCAD utilities.

Another version of FreeCAD had libs in the `/usr/libs/freecad-python3` directory.
Now there is nothing there.
The installed program exists in `/snap/freecad`, but there are so many folders and files there.
Does anyone know which one should i include, in order to import Draft, FreeCAD etc?

Comment: Read the makefile - it may show where they get copied to.